# How to get the time of one zone into UTC?

Tags: java

I want to convert `2019-12-27 08:17:09` (America/New_York) time zone in UTC.

Is there any built-in function to convert time of one zone into another ?

Comment: ..`ZonedDateTime`

Comment: Please add example regarding this

Answer (score 2):

You have to use `ZonedDateTime`.

Just do this :

```
    LocalDateTime localDateTime = LocalDateTime.parse("2019-12-27 08:17:09", DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss"));
    ZonedDateTime americanZoneTime = localDateTime.atZone(ZoneId.of("America/New_York"));
    ZonedDateTime utc = americanZoneTime.withZoneSameInstant(ZoneOffset.UTC);
    System.out.println("America Time : " + americanZoneTime + "\n UTC Time : " + utc);
```

Comment: This will give output in utc time,but how come we ensure "localDateTime" is in "America/New_York" zone?

Comment: Is the input time string in America/New_York zone ?

Comment: yes input string is in America/New_York zone and I want to convert America/New_York zone in UTC time

Comment: @NehaGour Then, you can simply pass the string and get the value in UTC. You don't need to check i guess.

Comment: But we need to tell right that from "America/New_York" zone we are converting into UTC so accordingly it will give us output

Comment: @NehaGour Is this Ok ?

Comment: Actually Input is americaTime
Why you are taking input in localdate time?

Comment: @NehaGour I have converted the string in `LocalDateTime` and then stored the time in `ZonedDateTime` by getting it according to the zone.

Answer (score 1):

```
import java.time.LocalDateTime;
import java.time.ZoneId;
import java.time.ZonedDateTime;
import java.time.format.DateTimeFormatter;

public class ZonedDateTimeExample {

    private static final String DATE_FORMAT = "dd-M-yyyy hh:mm:ss a";

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        String dateInString = "22-1-2015 10:15:55 AM";
        LocalDateTime ldt = LocalDateTime.parse(dateInString, DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern(DATE_FORMAT));

        ZoneId singaporeZoneId = ZoneId.of("Asia/Singapore");
        System.out.println("TimeZone : " + singaporeZoneId);

        //LocalDateTime + ZoneId = ZonedDateTime
        ZonedDateTime asiaZonedDateTime = ldt.atZone(singaporeZoneId);
        System.out.println("Date (Singapore) : " + asiaZonedDateTime);

        ZoneId newYokZoneId = ZoneId.of("America/New_York");
        System.out.println("TimeZone : " + newYokZoneId);

        ZonedDateTime nyDateTime = asiaZonedDateTime.withZoneSameInstant(newYokZoneId);
        System.out.println("Date (New York) : " + nyDateTime);

        DateTimeFormatter format = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern(DATE_FORMAT);
        System.out.println("\n---DateTimeFormatter---");
        System.out.println("Date (Singapore) : " + format.format(asiaZonedDateTime));
        System.out.println("Date (New York) : " + format.format(nyDateTime));

    }

}
```

Comment: 22-1-2015 10:15:55 AM
Its in which zone?

Answer (score 1):

What you can do is create an instance of ZonedDateTime with your input, then convert that to LocalDateTime by using toLocalDateTime() instance method of ZonedDateTime class, and then use the instance method atZone() of LocalDateTime to obtain the new ZonedDateTime for the new zone.

```
ZonedDateTime americaTime =... ;// Your American time
LocalDateTime localTime = americaTime.toLocalDateTime();
ZonedDateTime utcTime = localTime.atZone(ZoneOffset.UTC);
```

Comment: How to create instance of "2019-12-27 08:17:09" in ZOnedDateTime